# NLP text classification CountVectorizer Shape Error

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, decision-tree, text-classification

I have a text dataset which has one column for reviews and another column for labels. I want to build a decision tree model by using that dataset, I used vectorizer but it gives `ValueError: Number of labels=37500 does not match number of samples=1`  error. `vect.vocabulary_ returns {'review': 0}` review is the column name. So I think it does not fit to all data. Here is the code below, any help is appreciated.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test,y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data.iloc[:,:-1],data.iloc[:,-1:],
test_size = 0.25, random_state = 42)

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vect = CountVectorizer()
vect.fit(X_train)
X_train_dtm = vect.transform(X_train)
X_train_dtm = vect.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_dtm = vect.transform(X_test)

from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier 
DTC = DecisionTreeClassifier()
DTC.fit(X_train_dtm, y_train)
y1_pred_class = DTC.predict(X_test_dtm)
```

Also X_train_dtm.shape is `<bound method spmatrix.get_shape of <1x1 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>' with 1 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked when I changed this part:

X_train, X_test,y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data['text'],
data['tag'],test_size = 0.25, random_state = 42)

Answer (score 2):

`CountVectorizer` requires 1-dimensional inputs, and the error suggests that your `X_train` is 2d. If it's a dataframe, reduce to a series; if it's a numpy array, use `reshape` or `ravel`.